# Single tracking algorithm for many carriers

Tags: design-patterns, software

When it comes to tracking packages from a multitude of carriers, is it possible to wrap a globally accepted way of pulling tacking status or must I write support for each carrier we deal with?

I have software which processes EDI documents. I've implemented a ways to automatically invoice based on the status reported back from a tracking number. Our first trading partner uses only UPS -- simple. Done. No problem. The second however throws all of that out the window. It's all about freight with a select group of carriers and most of them support an API *BUT* I would like to not have to write, implement and update for every single one we must support. Not to mention the users can add more carriers.

Currently we'll only shuffle between 3 types of carriers so there isn't THAT much, but who knows? We could have 10 Trading partners by the end of the year and have to support 50% of the major carriers in our region. This work can grow quickly and I'm looking for a possible solution, if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described sounds like a classic case for using the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

At a higher level, the pattern is there to protect your application from changes occurring in external interfaces.  It also serves as a convenient mechanism to introduce new external interfaces while minimizing the change to your core application.

Here's a diagram to help visualize how things will lay out.

[image: class diagram]
<sub>*Click to expand*</sub>

The darker blue `PackageTracking` component represents your global function that you would call in order to track a package.

The green `Shipping Interface` represents a common set of functionality that you need to have from all of your shipping carriers.

The lighter blue `Carrier _ Wrapper` represents the wrapper functions you'll need to write to interface with each carrier.

Unfortunately, there's no easy way around having to write code against the particular EDI API of each carrier. The upside of this approach is that you only have to touch the one carrier's wrapper when they make changes. You don't have to touch the other carriers' wrapper code.

Comment: This about seems what I'm left with, and not badly. To find 1 code to rule them all seems highly unlikely at this time. I can also benefit from this particular pattern in various other places, such as support for all the different documents and document version that function similarly but have minor to major differences in their physical structure.

Comment: @DavidCarrigan Even if you found the one code to rule them all, remember that it would break the next time one of your external suppliers changed their interface.  After taxes and death, change in external interfaces is the next guaranteed thing in life.